# Using OpenNLP with Android?

Tags: android, voice-recognition, opennlp

I would like to use OpenNLP in my Android project. I imported the JAR and I can use it in my project but when I need to load a TokenizerModel (for example) I do not see how to proceed.

Cheers.

Comment: be more clear,show us what you've done.

Comment: @AIaye I done all the speech recogition part, now I need to "understand" what the user wants by using OpenNLP but to use it I need to load .bin models but I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: did you find what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example (originally written on Stack Overflow Documentation):

#### Sentence Detection using openNLP using CLI and Java API

using CLI:

```
$ opennlp SentenceDetector ./en-sent.bin < ./input.txt > output.txt
```

using API:

```
import static java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes;
import static java.nio.file.Paths.get;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class FileUtils {
/**
 * Get file data as string
 * 
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 */
    public static String getFileDataAsString(String fileName) {
        Objects.nonNull(fileName);
        try {
            String data = new String(readAllBytes(get(fileName)));
            return data;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

class sentecedetectorutil:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Objects;

import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel;

public class SentenceDetectorUtil {
    private SentenceModel model = null;
    SentenceDetectorME sentenceDetector = null;

    public SentenceDetectorUtil(String modelFile) {
        Objects.nonNull(modelFile);
        initSentenceModel(modelFile);
        initSentenceDetectorME();
    }

    private void initSentenceDetectorME() {
        sentenceDetector = new SentenceDetectorME(model);
    }

    private SentenceModel initSentenceModel(String file) {
        InputStream modelIn;
        try {
            modelIn = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        try {
            model = new SentenceModel(modelIn);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (modelIn != null) {
                try {
                    modelIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return model;
    }

    public String[] getSentencesFromFile(String inputFile) {
        String data = FileUtils.getFileDataAsString(inputFile);
        return sentenceDetector.sentDetect(data);
    }

    public String[] getSentences(String data) {
        return sentenceDetector.sentDetect(data);
    }

}
}
```

main class:

```
public class Main {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  SentenceDetectorUtil util = new SentenceDetectorUtil(
    "path//to//your//en-sent.bin");

  String data = "Welcome to Stackoverflow Documentation.This is the first example in OenNLP.";

  String[] sentences = util.getSentences(data);

  for (String s : sentences)
   System.out.println(s +"\n");
 }
}
```

output will be:

> Welcome to Stackoverflow Documentation.
>
> This is the first example in OpenNLP.

---

And you can find some basic stuff [here](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-sentence-detector-training.html)

lot of examples are covered in the above examples. that must do the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Putting my `.bin` model files in the `assets` folder and call the using `getAssets()` is working pretty fine.